# Paginate based on conditional with relationship

Tags: laravel, pagination, eloquent

I'm trying to paginate based on a conditional on a relationship. Thought this would work but it does not..

```php
Product::with(['manufacturer' => function($query){
    $query->where('name', '=', 'Maker');
}])->paginate(10)->toArray();
```

for some reason It only works on the first model. I can tell because its the only one loading the manufacturer data.

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

thanks!

Comment: So what do you want to do? Paginate `Product` or `Manufacturer`?

Comment: I would like to paginate a list of products based on the manufacturer name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel offers convenient way to query relationships ([docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations))

I think, this is what you want

```php
$products = Product::whereHas('manufacturer', function($q)
{
    $q->where('name', '=', 'Maker');

})->get();
```

You may add pagination and other things as you wish.